# cookie in redirected response

Tags: node.js, redirect, cookies, request

As shown in the image below, I am trying to get the `set-cookie` in the first redirect#1 response.

I succeed to get the response with `request` module by setting `followRedirect` to be false in the request options, but I still could not get the `set-cookie` from the header.

A similar discussion here: https://github.com/request/request/issues/1502

Anyone has managed to use any other module to get the cookie from redirected response? Thanks a lot in advance!

---

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`response.headers['set-cookie']` should return the values you want.